# Replace a pattern inside a string C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have string that look like :

> My name is Jason `<and maybe>` I just seem like `<a kid>` but I'm not

I want to mark everything that look like `<bla bla bla>` with

```
<span style='color:red'>bla bla bla></span>
```

This code:

```
string s = "My name is Jason <and maybe> I just seem like <a kid> but I'm not"; // the string with all the text inside
int start = s.IndexOf("<");
int end = s.IndexOf(">");
if (start >= 0 && end > 0)
{
    string result = s.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
    elem.LayoutText = s.Replace("<" + result + ">" , "<span style='color:red'>" + "<" + result + ">" + "</span>");
}
```

Replaces only the first occurrence , how can I replace all of them ?

Comment: This would be a great time to learn regex.

Comment: You need to encapsulate the finding of your start and end in an array until they both return negative numbers

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Regex:

```
string input = "My name is Jason <and maybe> I just seem like <a kid> but I not";
string regexPattern = "(<)([^<>]*)(>)";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regexPattern, m => "<span style='color:red'>" + m.Groups[2].Value + "</span>");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jvl0e0

Answer (score 1):

Without using regular expressions, you need to keep searching your string for the next start and end indexes.

You can accomplish this in a loop like this:

```
        string s = "My name is Jason <and maybe> I just seem like <a kid> but I'm not"; // the string with all the text inside
        int start = s.IndexOf("<");
        int end = s.IndexOf(">");
        while (start >= 0 && end > 0)
        {
            string result = s.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
            string rep = "<span style='color:red'>" + "<" + result + ">" + "</span>";
            s = s.Replace("<" + result + ">", rep);
            start = s.IndexOf("<", start +rep.Length + 1);
            end = s.IndexOf(">", end + rep.Length + 1);
        }
         elem.LayoutText = s;
```

Using a regular expression would simplify this:

```
        string s = "My name is Jason <and maybe> I just seem like <a kid> but I'm not";
        string pattern = "(<)([^<>]*)(>)";
        elem.LayoutText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, pattern, match => "<span style='color:red'><" + match.Groups[2].Value + "></span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

my variant:

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"\<([^<]*)\>");
Console.WriteLine(rg.Replace("aaez <cde> dfsf <fgh>.", "<span style='color:red'>$1</span>"));
```

because one capture group is enough